# unsetting css is not working

Tags: theming

I am trying to unsetting the deafult CSS through a foreach loop, but seems its not working in

```
hook_preprocess_html(&$variables)
```

here is my code, please have a look.

```
$arrCSS = drupal_add_css();
          foreach ($arrCSS as $key => $value) {
            unset($arrCSS[$key]['data']);
          }
          $all_css = drupal_add_css();
          print_r($all_css);
```

Comment: Please stop editing your questions to make them useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS should be manipulated using [`hook_css_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7), not in an HTML preprocess (where it's too late).

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Remove defaults.css file.
  unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'system') . '/defaults.css']);
}
```